# How I can add attribute to python object if its name is variable?

Tags: python

Hi I want add some attribut to python object.
But its name I don't know and it is a varieble.

In js it will be like this:

```
obj[somename] = 'str'
```

Comment: Heard of `setattr`?

Comment: See [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)

Comment: cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ khelwood how I can add array? and then push to this attribute?